# Organization based restrictions for participant identity issuing in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

lets say we have a 2 organization network (OrgA and OrgB) both organizations have there own "Admin" identity that can issue identities. If the admin identity for OrgA issues a identity for a participant "ParA", how can one prohibit OrgB to issue a identity for that participent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ACLs to restrict the kind of participants created or that are viewable, by either Organisation's admins. Simplest way is designated participant classes for each Org and control access to participants by class

Alternatively, they can be in the same participant class but have identifying Org metadata, ie. where you DO insist that the participants are created in the same participant class. Then (with ACLs in place) the org admin from 'another org' won't have the capability to bind an identity he issued, to the 'wrong' participant (ie one he should not even see, to bind it to), because a condition check in the ACL will prevent the access.

eg

```
rule myRule1 {
  description: "Org admin can see/access/create participants matching own org"
  participant(p): "org.acme.nwk.IssuerAdmins"  // ie only someone of this class, can 'issue identities' - 
  operation: ALL  // (CREATE, READ, UPDATE, DELETE) // do everything, for IDs in their Org ?
  resource(r): "org.acme.nwk.myParticipants"
  condition: (p.organisation == r.organisation) // can ONLY see or do anything with participants from own Org
  action: ALLOW
}
```

An Org Admin from a 'different' org - can issue identities, but will not be able to see a participant 'not in his/her Org' (to try map to his own org's identities).

Its possible to be more 'succinct' and base it on data, but putting complex javascript evaluations (check the attribute value for an Org pattern sequence etc) adds more overhead, if large amounts of data is being compared against.
you could also do another way:

Comment: Ok, so extend my participants to include metadata for the organization they belong to. Then using ACL limit so only participant from organization A can create/update identity for  participants in the same organization? How can one write such a ACL, the ACL syntaxis gives only participent, resource and condition.

Comment: The upper solution is fine and will work for my case thanks, but what if you wan to grand READ, for participants, let say you want to provide a way for psriaipents from different organization to trade resources. For that you must access the ID of the revising participant, and if so you can issue a identity

Comment: yes, participants will need an identity mapped to it - to then access the network. Its easy in the ACL runtime rules to check who the current participant is - and whether another Org's participant (supplied to the transaction, as he's allowed to 'revise') is accessing it and grant a READ/UPDATE (if that's what you want the rule to do).

Comment: on first question `extend my participants` - check out the ACL language guide -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/acl_language or the ACL tutorial in the tutorials section of the docs