# Hyperledger Composer: Assets owned by Multiple Participants

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, identity, hyperledger-composer, membership

I want to create Composer network with multiple organizations. In this network, organizations own assets. Participants authorized by that organization then have permission to access those assets and invoke trading functions on them to say, give an Asset to another organization.

How do I model this sort of network in composer? From reading the docs, it seems that Organizations are really more for setting up the peers, endorsers, and who can add participants, but that Assets themselves are tied to particular participants. Do I have some sort of fundamental misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the ACLs are driven by Participant.  User Identities are issued by Organisations and bound to Participants.  So modelling ACLs around Organisations is not straightforward.  The simple solution is to have different participant Types/Classes for each Organisation, but that might not be convenient.

This [previous Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50680188/organization-based-restrictions-for-participant-identity-issuing-in-hyperledger/50681159#50681159) shows a method of programatic ACLs to work with the Organisations.